# need suggestions for a more simplified devise user authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an intranet site in Rails 4 using the devise gem. What I am currently at right now is a root page that prompts the user to sign in to be able to access to the different modules page.

Now on to my question: Is there a more elegant way to authenticate the user aside from planting an if `user_signed_in?` on each of the pages ? I'm a little bothered if I have to use that on each of my pages beyond the login form.

Comment: You can use `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller for authentication..

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a before action in the application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login
end
```

For controllers / actions which do not require a signed_in user, you can use the skip_before_action e.g.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:index]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `devise` gem as below for authentication:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    ...

end
```

and if you want you can skip the authentication in any of the controller actions by using :

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

or

`skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:action1, :action2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an authorization gem like Pundit or CanCanCan which would integrate with Devise and allow you to set up restrictions to methods etc on a seperate policy file.

Take a look at this

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit

Answer (score 0):

Use a before filter on the `authenticate_user!` method:

**controller:**

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :protected_page

def protected_page
# ...
end
```

If a user isn't signed in, they will be directed to sign in.